# Am I eating enough for a bulk?

Tags: muscle, nutrition, calories, weights, breakfast

5'9 and weigh 139 pounds. I've decided to bulk and need help on my diet. This is what I ate today and I was wondering whether I should be eating more, or less to gain muscle and at the same time not gain as much fat. (Some fat will obviously be gained as a result of bulking)

breakfast: Granola with 2% milk = 400 calories
Lunch: A turkey/Cheese on sourdough with lettuce and greek yogurt: 600 calories

I then ran 2 miles and lifted weights for around an hour, straight.

Dinner: Ate two home made bean and cheese burritos with black beans, lettuce, whole wheat thin tortillas, and low fat cheese. - (500-600 calories)

Desert: A bowl of Baskin Robbins chocolate ice cream (400-500 calories) (Chocolate is my weakness :'( )

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: At best, that's 2100 kcal. For you, that's probably a calorie deficit, especially considering the training you do on top of it!

Comment: Yep, you're most likely going to lose weight, at best maintain and definitely not gain any weight. Try adding caloric foods such as rice, potatoes, or bread to your meals, and certainly more protein (steak, chicken, fish).

Comment: So...25% of your caloric intake is ice cream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd eat about double what you describe if I were running and lifting and wanted to gain weight. I'd particularly eat more protein: eggs at breakfast (in *addition*, not *instead*) and meat for dinner. I'd consider a nightcap of milk or yogurt to top myself off.

I'd also consider not running so much if I wanted to gain weight.

I'd also drink full-fat milk and cheese, whether I wanted to gain weight or not.

Comment: "I'd also drink full-fat milk and cheese, whether I wanted to gain weight or not." Why?

Comment: @Antrim Why not? The entire idea of reduced-fat dairy is predicated on myth: the myth that eating fat makes you fat, the myth that fat is bad for the heart. Call it what it is: *high-carb* dairy, with less satiating power and less of the nutrients that I want.

Comment: I'm with you, I was just wondering if you were referring to anything that applied to everyone else (such as non-fat products being unhealthier because of X reason) and not just your personal preferences.

Comment: @Antrim I would say that those reasons are general: someone trying to lose weight should eat/drink (limited amounts of) full-fat dairy rather than reduced-fat dairy because of its high carb content and reduced satiating power, and someone trying to gain weight should avoid reduced-fat dairy because they should want the well-balanced macronutrient profile and caloric power of full-fat.

Comment: Understood and agreed.